# Vector valued function in Euclidean space

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Suppose $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R} ^3$
>   is differentiable and $| f(t)| = 1$ for every $ t ∈ \mathbb{R}$.
>
> Show that $ f'(t) · f(t) = 0 $ for
>   every $ t ∈ \mathbb{R}$.

I am kind of unsure here: I was thinking about Cauchy Schwartz inequality but not sure how to use $| f(t)| = 1$

What do you think I should start from? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint: Think of how the the norm is defined for vector-valued functions. Can you find a way to rewrite $f'(t) · f(t) = 0$ in this form?

Answer (score 1):

We have $|f(t)|^{2}=1$, or $f(t)\cdot f(t)=1$, apply $d/dt$ both sides we have $2f(t)\cdot f'(t)=0$.